# Gradle upload sources.jar and aar to jfrog artifactory. artifactoryPublish will generate two pom-default.xml, it will pushlish one of them randomly

Tags: android, gradle, jar, artifactory, aar

i have a android project with kotlin, it includes a library module, i would like to upload this library to jfrog artifactory. i have uploaded an aar file to artifactory successfully. now i would like to upload library-sources.jar to artifactory. But when i execute gradle task **artifactoryPublish**, it will generate two pom-default.xml files, and publish one of them randomly.

**Project build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
      ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.30"
      repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my_virtual_repo/"
        }
      }
      dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.15.2"
      }
    }
    allprojects {
      repositories {
          maven {
              url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my_virtual_repo/"
          }
      }
    }
```

**library build.gradle**

```
......

apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
apply plugin: "maven-publish"

def MAVEN_LOCAL_PATH = "http://localhost:8081/artifactory"
def GROUP_ID = "com.xxx.artifactlib"
def ARTIFACT_ID = "artifactlib"
def VERSION_NAME = "1.3"

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    group = 'jar'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = GROUP_ID
            artifactId = ARTIFACT_ID
            version = VERSION_NAME
            artifact tasks.sourcesJar
            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")
                configurations.api.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode("dependency")
                    print(it.group)
                    dependency.appendNode("groupId", it.group)
                    dependency.appendNode("artifactId", it.name)
                    dependency.appendNode("version", it.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    publications {
        aar_pub(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = GROUP_ID
            artifactId = ARTIFACT_ID
            version = VERSION_NAME

            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")
                configurations.api.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode("dependency")
                    dependency.appendNode("groupId", it.group)
                    dependency.appendNode("artifactId", it.name)
                    dependency.appendNode("version", it.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactoryPublish {
    contextUrl = MAVEN_LOCAL_PATH
    publications("mavenJava", "aar_pub")

    clientConfig.publisher.repoKey = "my_local_repo"
    clientConfig.publisher.username = "xxx"
    clientConfig.publisher.password = "xxx"
}
......
```

**pom-default.xml of aar_pub**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xxx.artifactlib</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactlib</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies/>
</project>
```

**pom-default.xml of mavenJava**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xxx.artifactlib</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactlib</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <dependencies/>
</project>
```

how to upload a given pom file(like pom-default of aar_pub)? thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single `Publication` contains all artifacts for a single release.

You defined two identical `Publications` (well, both have the aar and pom, only one of them has sources JAR) and are trying to upload both of them to the same coordinates at the same time.

- Don't define one `Publication` for each of `aar`, `jar`, `pom`, whatever.
- Merge all articacts into a single `Publication`.

In your case:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = GROUP_ID
            artifactId = ARTIFACT_ID
            version = VERSION_NAME

            artifact tasks.sourcesJar
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")
                configurations.api.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode("dependency")
                    print(it.group)
                    dependency.appendNode("groupId", it.group)
                    dependency.appendNode("artifactId", it.name)
                    dependency.appendNode("version", it.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactoryPublish {
    publications("mavenJava")
}
```

#### Potential issues

There's no formal relationship between the publication and whatever task that produces the AAR. You'll have to manually execute `assemble` before `publish`. (And remember to do that every time.)

Consider migrating to Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.0 or newer which supports `maven-publish` plugin natively. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin). This has the following benefits:

- You don't have to manually write dependencies to POM.
- Whenever AAR would change the publication would pick it up automatically. (You don't publish *nothing* after a clean build. You don't have to manually execute `assemble` before `publish`.)
- You still have to handle sources JAR until support for `withSourcesJar()` is added to AGP. See [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145670440).

In your case it would look something like this:

```
// Because the components are created only during the afterEvaluate phase, you must
// configure your publications using the afterEvaluate() lifecycle method.
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                // Applies the component for the release build variant.
                from components.release
                artifact tasks.sourcesJar

                groupId = GROUP_ID
                artifactId = ARTIFACT_ID
                version = VERSION_NAME
            }
        }
    }

    artifactoryPublish {
        // ...
    }
}
```